# Has the CMD, "chkdsk c: /r" been depreciated in Windows 10 version 1703?

Tags: windows-10, chkdsk, windows-10-v1703

I notice that the CMD line "chkdsk c: /r" no longer seems to work in Windows 10 version 1703. When it is invoked, and I reboot the PC, the expected pre-boot chkdsk does not run at all. Instead, Windows just re-starts the OS and I am taken right back to the logon screen. This behavior is on three different machines, including 2 Dell M6500, one Thinkpad T60, and a Toshiba Satellite.

Has Microsoft depreciated the CMD line chkdsk utility? With Developers update? Does Windows just self-run chkdsk or find drive errors on its own now?

Answers or comments are welcome.  Thanks.

Comment: My research indicates this is behavior is caused by your AV software preventing access to the drive but the error message is displayed very quick and easily missed

Comment: I upgraded one of my old laptops tonight, and witnessed the exact same problem when I went to test `chkdsk c: /r` after the 1703 update.  Either both of us had some very bad luck behind-the-scenes with the Creators Update, or there is a bigger problem occurring with version 1703.

Comment: Addendum:  I just got home from work, powered-on that same laptop, and it immediately started into the `chkdsk` scan.  Either there was something wrong before, or perhaps there is something unusual about version 1703 where a "warm reboot" won't initiate a scheduled `chkdsk` scan, but a full shutdown will?

Comment: I now notice that as of 161.76.100 CHKDSK /C: /R is working again and seems to behave normally now.